# How to change selected row labels area in vue-good-table

Tags: vuejs2, vue-good-table

I'm using vue-good-table and I'm trying to change the labels area in the selected row box. Looking at the [documentation](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/checkbox-table.html#selected-row-action-slot) the only slot available is the selected-row-actions.

Is there a way/slot to edit the left side with the labels and 'clear' action? (not just their text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

As mentioned earlier there isn't any direct configuration from library to achieve what you want to achieve. CSS only solution will look like following, take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-jqs7f):

```
<template>
...
</template>
<style>
.vgt-selection-info-row {
  font-size: 0 !important;
}
.vgt-selection-info-row__actions.vgt-pull-right {
  visibility: visible;
  float: none !important;
}
</style>
```

**Original answer:**

There isn't any thing like that supported from the library out of the box. You can use `table-actions` slots to display table level actions on top right or can use `selected-row-actions` slot to display actions for selected row on the selection info bar like:

```
<div slot="selected-row-actions">
  <button @click="countSelected()">Sected Row Action</button>
</div>
<div slot="table-actions">
  Table Actions 
</div>
```

[image]

That being said, its HTML we are talking about (yay!) so nothing is preventing you from overriding default styles of the library.

You can use following style to use `selected-row-actions` slot and move slot next to clear button:

```
<template>
...
<div slot="selected-row-actions">
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <button @click="countSelected()">Action 1</button>
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <button @click="countSelected()">Action 2</button>
</div>
...
</template>
<style>
  .vgt-selection-info-row__actions.vgt-pull-right {
    float: none !important;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline;
  }
  .vgt-selection-info-row__actions.vgt-pull-right div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

PS: There is already a closed issue [BUG 519](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/519) for the library if you like to reopen it and track.

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking to change the "x rows selected" and the "clear" action to different once.

Comment: @amitdar not from the framework but you can still use CSS to hide infobar main actions and display custom actions with only CSS change. LEt me add that as well.